# How to make the editing time for my own comments longer?

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-edits

that's awful. The time left to edit my own comments is absolutely not enough. Why should it be, that 8 minutes after I have written something, I cannot edit my own text? It happened already several times that something turns me away (the colleague asking an urgent question, a phone call etc.) and then I have a text which is incorrect as it is, and I have no power to change it. This should be changed! Each of us must be an owner of his own words.

Comment: But why do you need to preserve the timestamp? You can delete your old comment and post a corrected version.

Comment: @Pickett but that throws off the order in case others already responded.

Comment: @YvesKlett Yes, but in that case I would argue that they may have acted upon what you wrote.

Comment: @Pickett right, that is the dilemma. But quite often I´d like only to correct some spelling issue. Mostly then, those are locked into the system.

Comment: @MrWizard Yes, of course, I would like to make the discussion as efficient as possible.

Comment: @Pickett How to delete the comment?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch When you hover your cursor over the comment a small cross appears next to the timestamp. If you click it the comment gets deleted. You can do this for comments of any age.

Comment: @Pickett Thank you, this already can solve some problems, though not all of them.

Comment: @ rm -rf Thank you, I have no doubt that this problem has already been raised. Needed are not discussions. Needed are actions. The more that much of the discussions there are childish, eg. of the sort: "Since the freedom may sometimes bring  harm (which is true), let us completely refuse of any freedom". We typically do not agree with statements in such  social forms, but accept them in this concrete embodiment.

Comment: @Alexei Sorry, I forgot to migrate this.  Doing it now.